# Trying to only type check boxes in specific cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to avoid the Developer checkboxes so I found this code, but need multiple columns to be check boxes. Specifically columns 4,5,6.

I know its simple. Here is what I am working with

```html
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
    'Column D
        If .Column <> 4 Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        If Asc(.Value) = 168 Then
            .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
            .Value = Chr(254)
        Else: .Value = Chr(168)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test columns **D, E, F**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
    'Column D & E & F
        If .Column = 4 Or .Column = 5 Or .Column = 6 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            If Asc(.Value) = 168 Then
                .Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                .Value = Chr(254)
            Else
                .Value = Chr(168)
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way I can limit these wingdings to a range. Say D3:F13 or D3:lastrow & E3:lastrow & F3:lastrow?

Comment: This is what I got for a range of D3:F13. Not sexy but it works anything simpler is much appreciated. If .Column = 4 And (Target.Row >= 3 And Target.Row <= 13) Or .Column = 5 And (Target.Row >= 3 And Target.Row <= 13) Or .Column = 6 And (Target.Row >= 3 And Target.Row <= 13) Then